# Drools 5.4.0.Final Cannot run on Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, drools

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The Eclipse JDT Core jar is not in the classpath
```

I am running into above error when I try to build my class. I am using `Drools 5.4.0.Final` and I have manually added `ecj-4.5.1.jar` to my build path but it still says:

> JDT core not in class path.

I am using `Eclipse Mars`, `Jdk 1.8`, `drools 5.4.0.Final`

Can anyone suggest a solution?

EDIT: (StackTrace Added)

```
 [echo] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'droolsProcessingFactory' defined in class path resource [com/opr/amt/atm/testConfig.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.att.lpp.fw.drools.factory.DroolsProcessingFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
 [echo] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.drools.factory.DroolsProcessingFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
 [echo] Caused by: org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
 [echo]     at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:313)
 [echo]     at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildDialectConfigurationMap(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:298)
 [echo]     at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:187)
 [echo]     at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.<init>(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:165)
 [echo]     at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:301)
 [echo]     at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.<init>(PackageBuilder.java:229)
 [echo]     at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:34)
 [echo]     at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:46)
 [echo]     at com.drools.factory.DroolsProcessingFactory.<init>(DroolsProcessingFactory.java:21)
 [echo]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 [echo]     at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
 [echo] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The Eclipse JDT Core jar is not in the classpath
```

Comment: Could you include the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed after I added ecj-4.5.1.jar. The issue was that ecj jar must be under the same class path as the project. Adding ecj jar under the library folder itself will not work it seems, if the class path of the jar is different.